# PG_DUMP LDAP authentication failed / no pg_hba.conf entry for host "x.x.x.x"

Tags: postgresql

Hello everyone I have a problem when I try to launch pg_dump from an ec2 install on which I instaleld postgres

**Command:** pg_dump -U  "xxxxx"  -h  x.x.x.x -p 2006 -d "xxxxx"  -Fc --schema="test" -v -f test

**pg_dump: error:** connection to server at "x.x.x.x", port 2006 failed: FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "xxxxx"
connection to server at "x.x.x.x", port 2006 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "x.x.x.x", user "xxxxxx", database "xxxxxx", SSL off

**/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf**

##### TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

##### "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only

local   all             all                                     trust

##### IPv4 local connections:

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust

##### IPv6 local connections:

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0                trust

##### Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the

##### replication privilege.

local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::/128                  trust

**/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf**
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;

pg version : 15
Thanks for the help.

I'm expecting to run a pg_dump from my ec2 instance to dump data inside that ec2

Comment: To question text add as text the answers to the following: 1) Are you really running Postgres on port `2006`? 2) Have you modified `pg_hba.conf` to include the IP address of the machine that the `pg_dump` is running on? And then reloaded the Postgres server? FYI, this `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust` is a) Not a local connection. b) Is just inviting the world to hack your database.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the remote pg server that I'm trying to reach is using that port. I didn't add the ip of the of the remote server on pg_hba.conf. basically, I'm just testing so I will not use host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust in the future ( i'm executing pg_dump to make a dump of a database on anotehr server)

Comment: 1) Its not the future you have to worry about, it is the now. I would remove those lines immediately. 2) If the `pg_hba.conf` you are showing is from your `EC2` instance then its contents will have nothing to do with you connecting to the remote server. The `pg_hba.conf` contents are for what clients a Postgres server will allow to connect. You would need to have access to the remote server `pg_hba.conf` or have someone that manages it provide you with the correct credentials to connect. In this case that seems to involve `LDAP`.